# Multiplication of large numbers which are stored as Array Lists of Character type

Tags: java, arraylist, multiplication

```
 private ArrayList<Character> product(ArrayList<Character> list1, ArrayList<Character> list2) {
        int size1 = list1.size();
        int size2 = list2.size();
        ArrayList<Character> list3 = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> list4 = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int index = (size2 -1); index >= 0; index--) {
            int carryOver = 0;
            int charInt1 = (int) ( list2.get(index) -'0');
            int count = index;
            while(count > 0) {
                list3.add('0');
                count--;
            }
            for ( int key = 0; key < size1; key++) {
                int charInt2 = (int) ( list1.get(key) - '0');
                int product = (charInt1 * charInt2) + carryOver;
                char intChar = (char) ( (product % 10) + 48);
                list3.add(intChar);
                carryOver = product / 10;

            }
            if ( carryOver != 0) {
                char carryChar = (char) ( carryOver + 48);
                list3.add(carryChar);
            }

            list4 = sum (list3, list4);
            list3.clear();

        }
        return list4;
    }
```

This is for multiplication of large numbers which are stored in ArrayLists of Character type. This piece of code does not work for cases such as 32 * 32, 91 * 11. The method sum is working perfectly.

Comment: Do you do this as an exercise or do you want to use it in a real app? If you want to use it in a real app, please take a look at `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Why are you multiplying *Characters*?

Comment: What *is* your question? Please add a [javadoc comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) to `product()` telling how the parameters will be interpreted. Add comments to your code or improve it where something happens that needs explanation (what's the significance of `48`?). Do you *need* capabilities of `List<Character>` `StringBuilder` lacks?

Comment: Arnaud Denouelle, It`s part of the the project I am doing. Professor wants us to do this operation using user input string to create BigInt objects which have array list of character data field.

Comment: #Nichlas, #greybeard
Characters representing integer values are stored in array list so I have to change character to integer value, multiply with another integer value ad store the resulting integer as character in new array list.